# jQuery With Mustache js Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, mustache

I'm using jQuery and Mustache Js in a project.

I have the template in a script tag. The template requires some dynamic/variable html based on some data. Hence I load the template using jQuery, manipulate it, and then write it back into the script tag.

However, loading the template into a div(for manipulation), using jquery seems to alter the structure of the template (it moves things around), which invalidates the template.

**How do i update the template dynamically and avoid this issue? (Any help / Pointers / etc)**

Original Template

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>FN</td>
            <td>SN</td>
            <td>OT</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>{{#Users}}
        <tr class="tr-border" data-row-id="{{DCSID}}">
            <td class="td-border">{{FN}}</td>
            <td class="td-border">{{SN}}</td>
            <td class="td-border">{{OT}}</td>
        </tr>{{/Users}}</tbody>
</table>
```

Loading with jquery into another div causes this below(**moves {{#Users}} {{/Users}} out of place**)

```
   {{#Users}} {{/Users}}
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>FN</td>
                <td>SN</td>
                <td>OT</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody><tr class="tr-border" data-row-id="{{DCSID}}">
                <td class="td-border">{{FN}}</td>
                <td class="td-border">{{SN}}</td>
                <td class="td-border">{{OT}}</td>
            </tr></tbody>
    </table
```

The code below is how I'm going about it. Also this is a js fiddle [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/spidergeuse/kLgA4/2/)

```
var $newDcsTemplate = $('<div/>').html($('#dcs-template').html()); // for manipulation
var original1 = $('#dcs-template').html()
var original2 = document.getElementById('dcs-template').innerHTML;

// manipulate the template here and replace content of script tag with it.


console.log(original1); // works fine
console.log(original2) // works fine
console.log($newDcsTemplate.html()) // messed up the template
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is being modified by the DOM because you're inserting it into a `<div>` as "HTML", which it isn't. It's doing exactly what a browser would do if you gave it that markup. It's putting the `{{# Users }}` in the nearest available valid place to put it.

This is the same reason your template is originally stored in a `<script>` tag. You should always use `<script>` tags to hold your templates, and you should always use `.text()` to read and write them:

```
var $newDcsTemplate = $('<script/>').text($('#dcs-template').text());
console.log($newDcsTemplate.text())
```

Comment: Thanks. To be able to edit the content though, you need to load it into something else but the <script/> tag as I couldn't get .find() to work on $newDcsTemplate when i goes thought the <script/> but it does work with <div/>

Comment: The problem you'll run into is that you can't use the DOM to manipulate things that aren't valid HTML, and templates will almost never be valid HTML.

Comment: Well, with the sample I provided above, once I have fetched the template into a div tag, I'm able to manipulate the content of the div
The snippet below finds the element with id dcs-type-list from the template without issues

var $newDcsTemplate = $('<div/>').html($('#dcs-template').html());
var $dcsTypeTable = $newDcsTemplate.find('#dcs-type-list');

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this, with `.html()` and without `</script>`:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>FN</td>
      <td>SN</td>
      <td>OT</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- {{#Users}} -->
    <tr class="tr-border" data-row-id="{{DCSID}}">
      <td class="td-border">{{FN}}</td>
      <td class="td-border">{{SN}}</td>
      <td class="td-border">{{OT}}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- {{/Users}} -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```